# How remove an element just after an animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I'd like to know how remove an element BUT only after an animation, when the animation is completed.

If I write

```
el.animation(...).remove();
```

el gets out of the paper but without any animation.
So perhaps should be some chaining function or something like that.

Comment: The last parameter of an animation is a callback function. You could add the remove to that maybe ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see the callback function.